# V-carousel is not supported in safari brower?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

V-carousel is not supported in the Safari browser?

```
<v-carousel
      hide-delimiters
      :cycle="true"
      :interval="duration"
      class="elevation-0"
      v-model="carouselIndex"
    >
      <v-carousel-item
        reverse-transition="none"
        class="carouselTrans"
        v-for="(img, i) in orderedImages"
        :src="`${apiurl}api/v1/assets/CPM/${img.image}/image`"
        :key="i"
        lazy-src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/10/6"
      >
        <v-flex class="imageSlideCount" v-if="!$vuetify.breakpoint.xs">
          <span class="title">{{i+1}}/{{orderedImages.length}}</span>
        </v-flex>
        <v-layout wrap>
          <v-flex xs12 class="carouselTitle bounceInRightTitle">
            <span v-html="current.title"></span>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex xs10 class="carouselDescription bounceInRightDesc">{{current.description}}</v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `not supported`? Please share more info, what errors do you get?